# How do I delete a selected column in SQL Server, inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, queue, sql-execution-plan

I am using SQL Server 2017 Express to implement a high-performance queue (FIFO push & pop) - by "high-performance", I mean every millisecond counts for my application.

I ended up implementing the queue's `pop` function like this:

```
BEGIN TRY  
    DECLARE @QueueID [int] = null;

    --get the id of the top 1 item
    SELECT TOP 1 @QueueID = [QueueID] 
    FROM [dbo].[ReceiverQueue] WITH (NOLOCK);

    --pop that item 
    SELECT [QueueDateTime], [Packet], [Status] 
    FROM [dbo].[ReceiverQueue] 
    WHERE [QueueID] = @QueueID 
    OPTION (FAST 1);

    --delete that item from the queue
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[ReceiverQueue] 
    WHERE [QueueID] = @QueueID;

    --return the popped columns 
    RETURN;
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    --return exception, if pop fails
    EXECUTE [dbo].[sp.GetLastError]
END CATCH;
```

Some of the solutions that I came across in StackOverflow uses temporary tables to persist the result-set within a stored procedure for further use (in my case for the `DELETE` statement that follows the `SELECT`); and I created a short variant of that as shown above...

Nevertheless, I was wondering whether there exists a variant like this?

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    @QueueID = [QueueID], [QueueDateTime], [Packet], [Status] 
FROM 
    [dbo].[ReceiverQueue] WITH (NOLOCK);
```

or this?

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[ReceiverQueue] 
WHERE [QueueID] = SELECTED.QueueID;
```

Tried similar, but in vain.

Thanks in advance.

PS: `QueueID` is an `IDENTITY` column

Comment: You can't use NOLOCK here, or multiple clients will get the same item.  See generally http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @David, appreciate it. That link is very useful; reading it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all of you; really appreciate the fast useful responses.

Combined your recommendations and coined a variant:

```
    --pop top 1 row
    DELETE TOP (1) FROM [dbo].[ReceiverQueue] OUTPUT DELETED.*;
    --return the popped columns 
    RETURN;
```

Worked like charm! :)

PS. The sort order could still be a mess as Serg pointed out; need to explore [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19159/sort-order-specified-in-primary-key-yet-sorting-is-executed-on-select) discussion in that regard... But for now, the above revision looks suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQL Server 2005 or higher (and if you don't, you really should upgrade), you can POP your data using the OUTPUT clause of the DELETE statement, like this:

```
DELETE 
FROM [dbo].[ReceiverQueue] 
OUTPUT deleted.[QueueDateTime], 
    deleted.[Packet], 
    deleted.[Status] 
WHERE [QueueID] = (
    SELECT TOP 1 [QueueID] 
    FROM [dbo].[ReceiverQueue] WITH (NOLOCK)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks @Vergil, this OUTPUT clause is awesome, going to try with it...

Answer (score 1):

If perfomance is a problem and you need ORDER BY to ensure deleted row is really the first one logically you may try deleting from CTE

```
with c as (
   SELECT top(1) *
   FROM [dbo].[ReceiverQueue] 
   ORDER BY [QueueID]
)
delete from c
output deleted.[QueueDateTime], 
    deleted.[Packet], 
    deleted.[Status]
```

Comment: That QueueID, while it is an identity column, it is also the primary key for that table; forgot to mention that, my apologies @Serg. And that's why I didn't use the ORDER BY clause. Will try it anyways.

Comment: @Noble,  Most probably, a simple `select top(1) from` the clustered table will return the row with a lowest id. But it is not guaranteed. In short, you can’t guarantee that the results will be returned in the order you expect, unless you make it explicit with an ORDER BY statement.

Comment: @Noble be careful. The clustered index does not guarantee that top will be ordered by the clustered index. See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/)

Comment: Definitely @Serge, will explore further. Specifying the ORDER BY at every transaction call worries me; If only I could find a way to guarantee the order at the metadata definition level, that will be awesome. Will keep looking.

Comment: There is one and **only** way to ensure data when you retrieve it, that is to use an order by clause. No amount of kludging or whatever can change this.

Comment: @Noble, Microsoft docs and blogs leave no doubts, no `ORDER BY` no guarantee. The code will run OK million of times and can fail one day and no one is to blame but the code author.